# How to elegantly initialize variables in Class in C++?

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
private:
   int a[100];
public:
   A();
};
```

Now I want to initialize `a` with 100 specified value.Except for typing `a[i]=XXX` in `A()`, do we have more elegant way?

Comment: In what form are those specific values existing? Are they part of a file that can be loaded? Do they need to be hard coded? Is there any pattern to those specific values?

Comment: For hard-coded, constant values you can use the in-class initialization with braced init list or a constructor. C++ does not incorporate reflection. There is nothing wrong with having hard-coded array elements in an intiializer list. Avoid raw arrays, and use a container such as `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.

Comment: I understood. It sounds that hard code is the only choice. The reason why I asked the question is that I can use aggregate initialization when the variable is not in a class.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::fill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill), eg:

```
#include <algorithm>

A::A() {
    std::fill(a, a+100, DesiredValue);
}
```